# Concatenation of Strings in new line in JAva

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate strings in new lines when a condition is met. This is my input:

```
Concept
soft top cove
tonneau cove
interior persennin
Concept
Innen
Innenraum
Platz im Inneren
```

All I want to do is to concatenate all the strings after the string concept and to get the following output:

```
lemma, surface
soft top cove, tonneau cove|interior persennin
Innen, Innenraum|Platz im Inneren
```

I know if a string value is equal concept I want to go to the other line and write the string of the next line before a comma, than the strings from the other lines delimited by "|" e.g. *soft top cove, tonneau cove|interior persenning*
This is my code so far. Any suggestions are welcome!
Thank you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader inputcsv = null;
             List <String> zeilencsv = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            inputcsv = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("ErsteDatei.csv"));
            String content;
            while ((content = inputcsv.readLine()) != null) {
                zeilencsv.add(content);

                System.out.println(content);
            }
            File outputcsv = new File("TwoColumnsResult.csv");
            //creates new file
            outputcsv.createNewFile();
            FileWriter csvFilewriter = new FileWriter(outputcsv);
            //arraylist loop
            int counter_a=0;
            int counter = 1;
            for (String zeile:zeilencsv){
                String concept = "Concept";

                //check string value =concept?
                        if(zeile.toString().equals(concept)){

                            zeile="lemma,surface";
                            for(String zeile2:zeilencsv){
                                //here I don't know how to say give me the next line, write it as a word , put comma and than concatenate with a |
                            }



                        }
                        else {

                        counter++;

}
                csvFilewriter.write(zeile+"\n");
                counter++;
            }
            //write
            csvFilewriter.flush();
            //closes the file
            csvFilewriter.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `if a string value is equal concept` ... you need to define what an equal concept is.  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Oh sorry, concept is just a string value "concept". I thought I could check it this way:

Comment: Oh sorry, concept is just a string value "concept". I thought I could check it this way:if(zeile.toString().equals(concept)) if this condition is met than take next line, write it in the output file, than write comma, go to the next line write this after the comma, go to the next line and concatenate this with the previous so long until the value of the line is equal "concept". Thx

Comment: unfortunatley I really have no idea how to write that in code.

Answer (score 0):

so if I understood correctly you want that after finding "Concept" save the next line as text, concatenate a comma, then save the next line and concatenate a | and then save the next?

Well the code that you're using is kind of bizarre but what I would do is the next:

```
zeile="lemma,surface";

// I'll put a counter to distinguish where to put "," and "|"
int counter = 0;

// Then I need a string variable to save the line
String line = "";

for(String zeile2:zeilencsv){
    if (count == 0){ //First iteration
        line = zeile2.toString();
    }
    if(count == 1){ . //Second iteration add the comma
        line = line + "," + zeile2.toString();
    }
    if(count == 2){ . //Second iteration add the pipe
        line = line + "|" + zeile2.toString();
    }
    count++;
}
```

I hope that this is what you're looking for. If you would like to optimize the code, feel free to send me a message and we could work together.

Comment: Great. Thank you. It's really in a nutshell and the right way. I think just something small is missing.

Comment: Awesome. What's missing?

Comment: In the output file I get the string conecpt as a value e.g. Concept,soft top cove|tonneau cove etc. But it's not needed. I need soft top cove, | tonneau cove | interior | persennig and I think I need a dynamic counter because now the counter stops at index 2.

Comment: I#ve adapted the code but somehow it doesn't work: `for(String zeile2:zeilencsv){
            if((zeile.toString().equals(concept)) & (counterb == 1))
            { //First iteration
               line = zeile2.toString();
               line = line + "," + zeile2.toString();
           }
           if(counterb == 2){  //Second iteration add the pipe
               line = line + "|" + zeile2.toString();
           }
           counterb++; 
       csvFilewriter.write(line +"\n");
         
       }`

Comment: Indeed. You need to tell your program that if zeile2.toString().equals(concept) use "continue;" to skip it. If you don't do that "line" will be equal to "concept" and because counter = 0; before the loop then that's why the counter stops at 2.

Comment: Thx Am I very naughty, if I please you you for a  concrete correction? This is my code now: `for(String zeile2:zeilencsv){
           
        if (zeile2.toString().equals(concept)){ //First iteration
         if (counterb == 0){ //First iteration
                line = zeile2.toString();
            }
              
           
           if(counterb == 2){  //Second iteration add the pipe
               line = line + "|" + zeile2.toString();
           }
       }
       }
       counterb++; 
       csvFilewriter.write(line +"\n");`